# Matplotlib transparent line plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting two similar trajectories in matplotlib and I'd like to plot each of the lines with partial transparency so that the red (plotted second) doesn't obscure the blue.

[image]

**EDIT**: Here's the image with transparent lines.

[image]

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Plain and simple:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', alpha=0.7)
```

(I know I add nothing new, but the straightforward answer should be visible).

Comment: I can't see where the alpha parameter is documented. Could you update the answer to include where this is documented?

Comment: @AlexSpurling the [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) takes keyword arguments for [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) which the alpha parameter, among others, is a property of.

Answer (score 38):

After I plotted all the lines, I was able to set the transparency of all of them as follows:

```
for l in fig_field.gca().lines:
    l.set_alpha(.7)
```

**EDIT:** please see Joe's answer in the comments.

Comment: All of the maplotlib plotting functions take an alpha parameter directly. You can just do `plt.plot(x, y, 'r-', alpha=0.7)`.

Comment: I would be glad to see the updated picture -- could you add it to this answer please?

Comment: @JoeKington: that seems to composit the lines before applying the transparency. Is there a way to do it the other way around, so that the transparent lines add together to get darker?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what functions you're using to plot the lines, but try see if the on you're using takes an alpha value and set it to something like 0.5. If that doesn't work, try get the line objects and set their alpha values directly.

Comment: The comment by @joe-kington says all the matplotlib functions take an alpha parameter, is your answer needing a correction or his comment?