# Gnuplot: line opacity / transparency?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot to successfully plot some time series data. However, the series are fairly dense (10,000's of samples in about 5 inches of space), and when I plot multiple series, it is hard to see underneath the series that was plotted on top. **Is there any way to make the lines have a bit of opacity or transparency (i.e. make the line transparent so underneath lines are visible)?**

Excel has this capability, but I would much prefer to use Gnuplot.

Below is a sample of what I'm talking about. You can't see the red lines under the green lines. I would actually like to add a third time series. I am plotting with the command:

```
plot [][-3:3] 'samples_all.csv' using 1:7 title 'horizontal' w l ls 1, '' using 1:8 title 'vertical' w l ls 2"
```

[image]

Comment: In a comment, another user (@stackoverflow2010) asked for another tool to plot such data.
You can have a look at Kst: https://kst-plot.kde.org/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Good news!  This has been implemented in gnuplot.  Example syntax is

```
plot x lw 10, -x lw 10 lc rgb "#77000000"
```

This will plot x as a red line and -x as a transparent black line (it looks gray).  The first pair of two characters in the rgb specification define the alpha (transparency) channel ("#AARRGGBB").  The normal syntax ("#RRGGBB") still works.

#### old (gnuplot < 5.0 or so) answer for reference:

If you want to make lines plotted for time series data, the answer is no (see discussion [here](http://old.nabble.com/transparent-lines-and-points-td25285912.html)).  You can't set a line style to be transparent.  Transparency only works for filling under curves, and it has to be printed to the right terminal type.

I ran into this problem myself recently, I hope this feature will be added in a future version of gnuplot.

Comment: Do you know of any other command-line (scriptable) tools to plot dense time series like the one I showed above? Like R maybe?

Comment: R maybe, and I think matplotlib can do it (if you use python), but I have not used either myself.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320021/matplotlib-transparent-line-plots)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 : I don't see any reason to not plot this data with filledcurves (which you *can* use transparency with) ...

Comment: @mgilson: Can you please provide an example of the equivalent gnuplot command to do filled curves? I only know how to use the basic plot command (shown in my original post).

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 -- `plot sin(x) w filledcurves y1=0 fs transparent solid .5 , cos(x) w filledcurves y1=0 fs transparent solid .5`.  This just plots sin and cosine, try it with your data.  Since your data is so dense, filling with the x axis shouldn't make a difference (other than now you get transparency).

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/transparency-in-gnuplot.html) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: That link mentions only fill color transparency, not line (stroke) transparency.