# Matplotlib - plotting transparent and overlapping time series

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I've been searching for a solution to generate a figure of overlapping time series, i.e., http://grollchristian.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/wpid-224.png?w=604
[image]

However, the only script I found online is done in R (above pic) or Matlab. What is my option under matplotlib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib transparent line plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320021/matplotlib-transparent-line-plots)

Answer (score 8):

In `matplotlib` it is controlled by `alpha` argument.

You can do: `plt.plot(x_data, y_data, color='black', alpha=0.4)`

Comment: Could it be possible to generate an interactive plot using any python libraries?