# Python: Matplotlib twin() issue: plotting spread

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some issue getting my code to run. The two lines in question are as follows (the code runs fine without them).

```
ax1_2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1_2.fill_between(date, 0, (ask-bid), alpha = 3, facecolor='g')
```

I'm looking to twin their x's and show another plot ontop of my current graph (displaying spread for my data).

Here's my source code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
        strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
        def bytesconverter(b):
                s = b.decode(encoding)
                return strconverter(s)
        return bytesconverter

date_converter = bytespdate2num("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

def graphRawFX():
    date,bid,ask=np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                            delimiter=',',
                            converters = {0: date_converter})
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    # gca() here because we want to offset here

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

    ax1_2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax1_2.fill_between(date, 0, (ask-bid), alpha = 3, facecolor='g') #fills betwween date and zero, ask-bid is the spread

    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.23)


    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

graphRawFX()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Could you attach a figure?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I hadn't given any information on the error. The left image shows the error, and the right image is the base plot that appears when I comment out the two lines I had mentioned in my original post. http://imgur.com/a/WNQKk

Comment: I do not have a computer at hand, but try to use an alpha-value between 0 and 1. 0=no color and 1=full color.

Comment: Sometimes, I realize the stupidity of the questions I ask. I meant to assign .3 to alpha, but missed the decimal point... Thanks for the help! If you want to post a solution, I'll give it a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comments to the OP, your `alpha` value is too big.  It has to be between 0 and 1.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320021/matplotlib-transparent-line-plots) or the [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_alpha).  What you want is

```
ax1_2.fill_between(date, 0, (ask-bid), alpha = 0.3, facecolor='g')
```